# Passing values in apex

Tags: eclipse, parameters, salesforce

This is a relatively straight forward question but one that has me stumped. In apex I am creating a new list of sObjects (see below):

public static sobjectPartnerSoapSforceCom.sObject_x[] retrieve(String fieldList, String sObjectType, String[] ids, String username, String password)

When I try to create a new sobjectPartnerSoapSforceCom.sObject_x I cant figure out how to pass the required parameters to the retrieve(...).

For example one of my attempts:
ListsObjectList = new                           List  ('id', 'Contact', contactSobjectId , 'blah', 'blah') ;

throws an error with "expecting right parenthesis, found ','.

How can I pass the required parameters to perform the retrieve statement?
Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The first parameter to retrieve is a String, so your field list should probably be:

```
String fieldList = 'id, Contact, contactSobjectId , blah, blah';
```

Then you make an array of Strings for the contact IDs you want:

```
List<String> ids = new List<String> { 'contactId1', 'contactId2' };
```

Then make the retrieve call:

```
soapBinding.retrieve(fieldList, 'Contact', ids, 'username@domain.com', 'thepassword');
```

Comment: Hi jeremy appreciate the fast response, I am now getting a method doesn't exist or incorrect sig on the soapBinding. Any ideas?